# SVG tag <use> doesn't work within polymer component in Firefox

Tags: html, svg, polymer, web-component

Here is an example: http://miriti.ru/svgtest/
If you'll look at this example in any browser you will see two grey squares with green circles (labled "Symbol") inside. Except for Firefox (I am testing on `Firefox 35.0.1` on windows and mac os x). 
These SVGs are absolutely identical but the second one is placed inside the polymer component.

Code on GitHub: https://github.com/miriti/svgtest

Any suggestion about what can be the cause of this problem?

Comment: You've two elements with the same id which is invalid but not the source of your issue. It looks like the script you're using to create the other markup is creating attributes using setAttribute when should use setAttributeNS for the xlink:href attribute of the use element.

Comment: Same ID shouldn't be a problem since the second SVG is encapsulated inside the Shadow DOM. About the second part. This is interesting. Probably I should dig dipper into the Polymer code...

Comment: No shadow DOM support in Firefox by default yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom The polyfill in the script just creates normal DOM elements so you do have a problem but it will go away once Firefox flips the shadow DOM support flag in release builds

Comment: The problem you experienced is inducted by `<use>` tag. Whether you would try the [example without `<use>`](http://www.html-5.com/tags/svg-tag/index.html), everything would be fine. I would suggest it’s because FF is unable to find the respective node (`#usingSymbol`) after the polyfill.

Comment: Yes it works without `<use>` tag but `<use>` it is pretty often used and very powerful tool when it comes to complex SVGs...

Comment: I reported an issue in Polymer project: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1182

Comment: AFAIU, this is not a Polymer problem. Once you have your page loaded in FF, open the Inspector, find the `<svg-component>`, right-click it, choose “edit as HTML”, type a space anywhere to force modification is applied—and voilá, the symbol is now rendered.

Comment: That is very interesting. Maybe this effect can lead to some workaround...

Comment: That just forces the html parser to rerun. It does not indicate a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to find a workaround for your problem. First of all, wrap your `<svg>` element with `<div id="content">`. This is necessary, because later we will reinitialize the inner content of this div.

```
<template>
  <div id="content">
    <svg width="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
      ...
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then in the script section do the following woodoo-magic:

```
  domReady: function() {
    this.async(function() { 
      this.injectBoundHTML(this.$.content.innerHTML, this.$.content); 
    }, this);
  }
```

Please don’t complain about the weirdness of this trick :)

You are done: FF is satisfied now.

Comment: Why do you blame Polymer when it’s clear that FF fails to handle `<svg>` nodes, indirectly injected in the document? Polymer’s polyfill does nothing on nodes, it transparently wraps them.

Comment: You're right, it is obviously a FF problem (even IE handles it!). But probably Polymer should consider this FF's behavior.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that Polymer should not force itself to go on crutches just because FF fails to handle some tags properly.

Comment: I don't think it's a FF bug. I see no setAttributeNS in the polymer code which is what you'd need to create an xlink:href attribute properly. Rerunning the parser forces the xlink:href attribute to be reparsed as a string which is why that works. I see no reason why FF should not implement the DOM specification properly just so that it can work around a Polymer bug ;-)

Comment: @RobertLongson :) Polymer, as I have already said, does not take care on foreign attributes. It manipulates DOM nodes, not their attributes. That’s why you don’t see any `setAttributeNS` in the code. On the other hand, whether you execute `document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('some:other', 42);` in FF, it will set the namespaced attribute with pleasure. The problem is somehow deeper.

Comment: No it won't, not properly.

Comment: @RobertLongson And, by the way, you might dump the DOM tree as I did, before and after injection; those are absolutely same. Even more, it is Polymer who parses string in the latter case. According to your claim that should ruin everything in FF, while it fixes everything.

Comment: @RobertLongson What does mean “not properly”? Try it yourself and compare DOM nodes.

Comment: **Of course** the DOM trees are the same they don't distinguish between an attribute xlink:href in the null namespace and a href attribute in the xlink namespace. On reparsing the html parser magically fixes the namespace because of the attribute name.

Comment: @RobertLongson That said the first time FF parser fooled :)

Answer (score 1):

Using SVG sprites I ran into issues that are similar to the one you describe but not the same. So what I propose is not exactly a solution to your problem, however you could avoid such issues altogether by using iron-iconset-svg (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons?active=iron-iconset-svg), which in my opinion provides a cleaner/easier solution. Its simply a wrapper for your SVG sprite sheet, so you define your icons almost the same way and use them with iron-icon.

**Defining a custom iconset** (put it directly into the page or wrap it inside an element + set a name that describes the icons, here: 'your-iconset-name')

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="your-iconset-name" size="24">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <g id="your-icon-name">
        <rect x="12" y="0" width="12" height="24" />
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" />
      </g>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

If you wrap them, lets say in 'your-custom-iconset', you can include the iconset like this:

```
<your-custom-iconset></your-custom-iconset>
```

**Using icons**

When you need an icon you just include iron-icons (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons) and place it like this:

```
<iron-icon icon="your-iconset-name:your-icon-name"></iron-icon>
```

You can then give it a class to apply styling and don't need to use 'fill' for its color, just use 'color'.

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. Please improve it, instead of shoving people off to other sites with a quick link. Take as a cue your last two answers, ... those looked awesome.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, so if i have the same answer here as to the other question, is it ok to just repeat it here?

Comment: just tailor it even thru some stretch of the imagination, or take some code and make it relevant here. The mods often go thru and delete things that are clearly lazy, same.

Comment: looks much better (I think, that is, I am not familiar with anything here). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it in Polymer 1.0 like this:

```
 attached: function () {
        //Fix "svg-use" in Firefox!! -> Properly bad for Performance (Issue: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1182)
        this.async(function () {
            this.$.content.innerHTML = this.$.content.innerHTML;
        }, this);
    }
```

but I don't use Bindings in my component (yet)