# Firefox render fail svg inside inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, svg

i have a problem with Firefox.

I have three anchor tags with svgs in it which I stack up horizontally using `display: inline-block;` in Chrome, Safari and even Internet Explorer everthing looks fine but in Firefox the anchor Tags have no width which seems to be the Problem.

Here is the Code for it:

```
<div class="share__icons">
        <a href="#">
          <svg class="share__facebook share__icon">
            <use xlink:href="#svgs-facebook" />
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <svg class="share__twitter share__icon">
            <use xlink:href="#svgs-twitter" />
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <svg class="share__mail share__icon">
            <use xlink:href="#svgs-share-mail" />
          </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
```

and the css

```
.share__icons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 }

.share__icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px; 
 } 

.share__icon {
 max-width: 58px;
 max-height: 58px; 
}

.share svg {
 fill: currentColor; 
}
```

and two images

how it looks in chrome:

http://mhrwg.li/1gEZA

how it looks in firefox:

http://mhrwg.li/X7ks

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Hey! I had similar problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474161/svg-tag-use-doesnt-work-within-polymer-component-in-firefox ). Looks like it is a bug in firefox - in some cases it fails to render SVG elements through `xlink:href` reference. Try to force firefox to update/rerender DOM. In my case it helped.

Comment: If you fail to specify width/height CSS properties or attributes on your `<svg>` elements it will likely not do what you want. Try 100% to begin with. If that doesn't work add the SVG markup that the `<use>` elements are pointing to to the question.