# SVG <use> tags within Polymer dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, polymer

I'm iterating over an object using dom-repeat, and want to reference different icons from an SVG sprite sheet with each iteration. To add an icon, I'm trying to use the `<use xlink:href="sprite.svg#id">` method, mixed with Polymer's computed bindings. Here's the code inside the dom-repeat block:

```
<template is='dom-repeat' items="{{currentPlan.functionalities}}">
  <div class="resourceRow rowParent">
     <div class="functionIconContainer columnParent">
        <svg><use xlink:href$="{{ _getIconURL(item.id) }}"/></svg>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

& the JS logic:

```
_getIconURL: function(iconID){
  var url = "sprite.svg#" + iconID;
  return url;
}
```

This code outputs what I want it to, as far as I can see in Dev Tools, but still the icon doesn't show up. For reference, here's an example of what is written to the DOM:

```
<svg class="style-scope">
   <use class="style-scope" xlink:href="sprite.svg#id"/>
</svg>
```

Is this a bug or my misunderstanding?

Comment: Does it work if you add the HTML manually (statically) to the DOM? Now it doesn't look related to Polymer. Where are the icons defined?

Comment: If I type 1 icon statically into the dom-repeat (so ``<use xlink:href="sprite.svg#icon1"/>``), it shows up as expected.

Comment: Is this only with a specific browser or several browsers?

Comment: I've tested both Chrome & Safari at the moment

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146886. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474161 could be related as well but seems only occur in FF

Comment: Have you tried telling Polymer that it's time to update?  See the docs on using `Polymer.dom.flush()` at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html

"Async operations. Insert, append, and remove operations are transacted lazily in certain cases for performance. In order to interrogate the DOM (for example, offsetHeight, getComputedStyle, etc.) immediately after one of these operations, call Polymer.dom.flush() first."

Comment: I did try flush(), but to no avail

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem before and ended up using iron-iconset-svg (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons?active=iron-iconset-svg), which in my opinion provides a cleaner/easier solution. Its simply a wrapper for your SVG sprite sheet, so you define your icons almost the same way and use them with iron-icon.

**Defining a custom iconset** (put it directly into the page or wrap it inside an element + set a name that describes the icons, here: 'your-iconset-name')

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="your-iconset-name" size="24">
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <g id="your-icon-name">
        <rect x="12" y="0" width="12" height="24" />
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" />
      </g>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

If you wrap them, lets say in 'your-custom-iconset', you can include the iconset like this:

```
<your-custom-iconset></your-custom-iconset>
```

**Using icons**

When you need an icon you just include iron-icons (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons) and place it like this:

```
<iron-icon icon="your-iconset-name:your-icon-name"></iron-icon>
```

You can then give it a class to apply styling and don't need to use 'fill' for its color, just use 'color'.

Applied to your example:

```
<template is='dom-repeat' items="{{currentPlan.functionalities}}">
  <div class="resourceRow rowParent">
     <div class="functionIconContainer columnParent">
        <iron-icon icon$="your-iconset-name:{{item.id}}"></iron-icon>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, not sure if this really counts as an answer, but it fixes my immediate problem. I've attached an `on-dom-change` event handler to the dom-repeat block, which gets called on well, DOM changes.
Then I loop through each icon container and set its innerHTML to itself. I don't know what it does, but it somehow forces a re-evaluation of that part of the DOM, causing my icons to show up. It's the simplest of code:

```
_forceRedraw: function(){
 var functionIcons = document.querySelectorAll('div.functionIconContainer');
  _.each(functionIcons, function(iconContainer){
    iconContainer.innerHTML = iconContainer.innerHTML;
  })
}
```

'Lo, it works!

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to add the attribute statically in addition to the binding

```
<svg><use xlink:href="" xlink:href$="{{ _getIconURL(item.id) }}"/></svg>
```

Polymer has issues with creating the attribute, updating it works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of: [Polymer (1.0) - dynamic use xlink:href$ inside template not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146886/polymer-1-0-dynamic-use-xlinkhref-inside-template-not-working-properly/36088418#36088418)

This is a Polymer bug, filed as issue [#3060](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3060).